# Figuring out issues raised by valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am trying to get size of an integer array in C by allocating required memory plus 1 and setting the last element to -1. I then create a function called getSize to determine the number of elements before this -1 element in an array, here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getSize(int * array)                                                        
{                                                                               
    int i=0;                                                                    
    while(1)                                                                    
    {                                                                           
        if(array[i] ==  -1) return i;                                           
        else i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int * array = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    memset(array,0,5);
    array[4] = -1;
    printf("\nsize = %d\n",getSize(array));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a just a test code but the function `getSize` is part of much bigger code, I ran valgrind on this code, this the issue I am getting:

> ==1683== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==1683==    at 0x100000EAE: getSize (in ./a.out)
>   ==1683==    by 0x100000F2E: main (in ./a.out)

Here's the summary:

> ==1683== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==1683==     in use at exit: 38,676 bytes in 425 blocks
>   ==1683==   total heap usage: 508 allocs, 83 frees, 44,948 bytes allocated
>
> LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==1683==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 2 blocks
>   ==1683==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==1683==      possibly lost: 13,130 bytes in 119 blocks
>   ==1683==    still reachable: 25,510 bytes in 304 blocks
>   ==1683==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==1683== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 20 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: `memset()` counts in bytes, you need to `memset(array, 0, 5*sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Corrected the memset but still same issues.

Comment: Are all of the issues still there? You can get rid of the memory leak by `free()`ing `array` after the `printf()`, but the uninitialized warning should be fixed. Did you recompile?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in this code. The valgrind output you have shown highlights two issues.

> ==1683== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==1683==    at 0x100000EAE: getSize (in ./a.out)
>   ==1683==    by 0x100000F2E: main (in ./a.out)

This is triggered by the if statement in getSize()

```
if(array[i] ==  -1) return i;
```

This seems at first glance as if it should be fine; in the main function you allocate memory using malloc, and then zero it using memset, before setting the last element to -1.

However, lets take a closer look

```
    int * array = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    memset(array,0,5);
```

You have allocated space large enough to hold 5 integers, so likely 20 bytes. You then attempt to memset this, however memset operates on a byte at the time - in other words the size should be the length in bytes, not integers.
So, after this operation, you have zero'd the 5 bytes. The rest of the memory is still uninitialized.

Next you use array notation to set the last integer to -1. This means you have a 20-byte buffer, with the first 5 and last 4 bytes initialized.

Going back to your getSize function, the first iteration in the for loop is fine, however the second , third and fourth iterations are reading uninitilized bytes, and performing a conditional jump based on this.

The second error we can see in the valgrind output is that you have leaked memory.

> LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==1683==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 2 blocks
>   ==1683==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==1683==      possibly lost: 13,130 bytes in 119 blocks
>   ==1683==    still reachable: 25,510 bytes in 304 blocks
>   ==1683==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==1683== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 20 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

In the definitely lost section, it is telling us you have lost 36 bytes in 2 blocks. There is actually only one leak in the code you presented, which is the memory allocated for `array`. You need to add this line:

```
free(array);
```

before returning from your function. Valgrind can give you more details on memory leaks - look for the hints in the output.